# The problem with playing tracks and playlists from vkontakte to Discord

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord

My Discord test bot is playing something, but it is silent and does not produce any voice. I do not understand what is wrong with the code, since there are no errors and `User-Agent` is added:

```
const { MessageEmbed, Permissions } = require('discord.js');
const { convertTime } = require('../../utils/convert.js');
const axios = require('axios');
const { access } = require('fs');


const USER_AGENT = 'VKAndroidApp/5.8.1 (Android 9.0; Transsion; RMA1852C; zh_CN; 1080x2340; 32bit; vk.com/app318634226)';
const VK_API_METHOD_BASE_URL = 'https://api.vk.com/method/';
const VK_API_VERSION = '5.87'; // Обязательно укажите актуальную версию API
const ACCESS_TOKEN = ''; // Токен, который вы получите после авторизации аккаунта vk
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  headers: {
    'User-Agent': USER_AGENT,
  },
});

async function getMp3FromM3u8(url) {
  // Not a m3u8 url
  if (!url.includes('index.m3u8?')) {
    return url;
  }

  const match = url.match(/^(.+?)\/(audio|(p[0-9]+)\/)?([^\/]+)/);
  if (match[2]) {
    return `${match[1]}/audio${match[4]}.mp3`;
  }
  return `${match[1]}/${match[3]}/${match[4]}.mp3`;
}


// **Используйте async/await для обработки асинхронных операций:**

async function searchVkTracks(query) {
  const response = await axiosInstance.get(`${VK_API_METHOD_BASE_URL}audio.search`, {
    params: {
      q: query,
      access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN,
      v: VK_API_VERSION,
    },
  });
  const data = response.data;

  if (data.error) {
    throw new Error(`Ошибка API ВКонтакте: ${data.error.error_msg}`);
  }

  return data.response?.items || [];
}

async function getVkTrackInfo(trackId) {
  const response = await axiosInstance.get(`${VK_API_METHOD_BASE_URL}audio.getById`, {
    params: {
      audio_ids: trackId,
      access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN,
      v: VK_API_VERSION,
    },
  });
  

  const data = response.data;

  if (data.error) {
    throw new Error(`VK API Error: ${data.error.error_msg}`);
  }

  return data.response?.items[0] || null;
}


module.exports = {
  name: 'vkplay',
  category: 'Music',
  aliases: ['vp'],
  description: 'Воспроизводит аудио или плейлист с VK.com ',
  args: true,
  usage: '<VK TRACK URL | VK Playlist URL | VK TRACK NAME>',
  userPrams: [],
  botPrams: ['EMBED_LINKS'],
  owner: false,
  inVoiceChannel: true,
  sameVoiceChannel: true,
  execute: async (message, args, client, prefix) => {
    if (!message.guild.members.me.permissions.has([Permissions.FLAGS.CONNECT, Permissions.FLAGS.SPEAK])) {
      return message.channel.send({
        embeds: [
          new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(client.embedColor)
            .setDescription('У меня недостаточно прав для выполнения этой команды! Пожалуйста, предоставьте мне разрешения `CONNECT` и `SPEAK`.')
        ],
      });
    }

    const emojiAddSong = message.client.emoji.addsong;
    const emojiPlaylist = message.client.emoji.playlist;

    const { channel } = message.member.voice;

    if (!message.guild.members.me.permissionsIn(channel).has([Permissions.FLAGS.CONNECT, Permissions.FLAGS.SPEAK])) {
      return message.channel.send({
        embeds: [
          new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor(client.embedColor)
            .setDescription('У меня недостаточно прав на подключение к вашему голосовому каналу. Пожалуйста, предоставьте мне разрешения `CONNECT` и `SPEAK`.')
        ],
      });
    }

    const query = args.join(' ');

    const player = await client.manager.createPlayer({
      guildId: message.guild.id,
      voiceId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
      textId: message.channel.id,
      deaf: true,
    });

    // **Определите тип запроса:**

    let tracks = [];

if (isVkTrackUrl(query)) {
  // **Получить информацию о треке:**
  const trackInfo = await getVkTrackInfo(parseVkTrackIdFromUrl(query));

  if (!trackInfo) {
    return message.reply('Трек не найден.');
  }

  tracks.push(trackInfo);
} else if (isVkPlaylistUrl(query)) {
  // **Получить список треков из плейлиста:**
  const playlistTracks = await getVkPlaylistTracks(parseVkPlaylistIdFromUrl(query));

  if (!playlistTracks.length) {
    return message.reply('Плейлист пуст.');
  }

  tracks = playlistTracks;
} else {
  // **Поиск треков по имени:**
  tracks = await searchVkTracks(query);

  if (!tracks.length) {
    return message.reply('Трек не найден.');
  }
}

// **Добавить треки в очередь:**

if (tracks.length > 1) {
  const uniqueTracks = [...new Set(tracks)]; // Remove duplicate tracks

  for (const track of uniqueTracks) {
    player.queue.add(track);
  }

  return message.reply({
    embeds: [
      new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(client.embedColor)
        .setDescription(`${emojiPlaylist} В очередь добавлено ${uniqueTracks.length} уникальных треков`)
    ],
  });
} else {
  player.queue.add(tracks[0]);

  return message.reply({
    embeds: [
      new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(client.embedColor)
        .setDescription(`${emojiAddSong} В очереди [${tracks[0].title}](${tracks[0].url})`)
    ],
  });
}

  
  }, 
};

// **Функции для проверки URL:**

function isVkTrackUrl(url) {
  return /https:\/\/vk\.com\/audio(\d+)(_\d+)?/.test(url);
}

function isVkPlaylistUrl(url) {
  return /https:\/\/vk\.com\/album\/(-\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)/.test(url);
}

// **Функции для парсинга URL:**

function parseVkTrackIdFromUrl(url) {
  const match = /https:\/\/vk\.com\/audio(\d+)(_\d+)?/.exec(url);
  return parseInt(match[1]);
}

function parseVkPlaylistIdFromUrl(url) {
  const match = /https:\/\/vk\.com\/album\/(-\d+)_(\d+)_(\d+)/.exec(url);
  return parseInt(match[1]);
}

// **Дополнительные функции:**

async function getVkPlaylistTracks(playlistId) {
  // ... код для получения списка треков из плейлиста ...
}
```

The screen console:
[image: console]

The Discord screen:
[image: Discord]

The link it gives out is: https://vk.com/mp3/audio_api_unavailable.mp3

I tried many options, but nothing worked despite of having no errors. I would be very grateful for any help.